# Click Hyperlink And Change CSS of ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

I think the title is obvious. I have hyperlinks on my page like;

```
<a href="#box1">LINK1</a>
<a href="#box2">LINK2</a>

<div id="box1">
content
</div>
<div id="box2">
content
</div>
```

box1 and box2 has no background but when i click the link1 and go to box1, is there a way to change the css of this visited box?

A simple draft in [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4kryeuz7/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract `id` from `hash` property

As hash returns `#box1`, it could be used as `id` selector

Use `attribute starts with` selector to select `#box(Anything)` elements

```js
$('a[href^="#box"]').on('click', function() {
  $(this.hash).css('background', 'green');
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#c:focused {
  background #d00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#box1">LINK1</a>
<a href="#box3">LINK2</a>
<a href="#box2">LINK3</a>

<div id="box1">
  content1
</div>
<div id="box2">
  content2
</div>
<div id="box3">
  content3
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a simple `onclick` event:

```
<a href="#box1" onclick="$('#box1').css({backgroundColor: 'yellow'})">LINK1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.click()` event to get reference to clicked element.

```js
$(".link").click(function() { // create click event for anchor tag using class
   var href =  $(this).attr("href"); // get href value
   href = href.replace("#",""); // remove # from href
   $(".content").css("color","black"); // first change color to back of all div
   $("#"+href).css("color","red"); // change css of div using href value as id
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#box1" class="link">LINK1</a>
<a href="#box2" class="link">LINK2</a>

<div id="box1" class="content">
content
</div>
<div id="box2" class="content">
content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution using jQuery is the following:

```js
$(function(){
    // attach a click handler for all links having the class js-link.
    $(".js-link").click(function(){

        // clear the background of all boxes.
        $(".js-box").css("background","000");
      
        // find the corresponding box's id.
        var box = $(this).data("target");
      
        // sets it's background.
        $(box).css("background", "#d00");
    });
});
```

```css
div{
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
#c:focused{
  background #d00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#box1" class="js-link" data-target="#box1">LINK1</a>
<a href="#box3" class="js-link" data-target="#box2">LINK2</a>
<a href="#box2" class="js-link" data-target="#box3">LINK3</a>
    
<div id="box1" class="js-box">
  content1
</div>
<div id="box2" class="js-box">
  content2
</div>
<div id="box3" class="js-box">
  content3
</div>
```